# Cylinder VBO OpenGL: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: opengl, vbo

I tried to create a cylinder VBO by passing a **std::vector** to the vertex buffer instead of the **static const GLfloat variableName[]= { some data};** . However, nothing gets drawn in my window.

What's wrong with my code?

**My VBO:**

```
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer2);
std::vector<float> bufferData = CreateCylinder();
glBufferData(
    GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    sizeof(bufferData),
    &bufferData.front(),
    GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

**CreateCylinder method:**

```
std::vector<float> CreateCylinder(){
    std::vector<float> outputArray;
    int i, j, k;
    for (j = 0; j <= 360; j += precision_deg){
        outputArray.push_back(float(cos((pi / 180 * j))));
        outputArray.push_back(1.0);
        outputArray.push_back(float(sin((pi / 180 * j))));
        outputArray.push_back(float(cos((pi / 180 * j))));
        outputArray.push_back(-1.0);
        outputArray.push_back(float(sin((pi / 180 * j))));

    }
    for (i = 1; i >= -1; i -= 2){
        outputArray.push_back(0.0);
        outputArray.push_back(float(i));
        outputArray.push_back(0.0);
        for (k = 0; k <= 360; k += precision_deg){
            outputArray.push_back(i*float(cos((pi / 180 * k))));
            outputArray.push_back(float(i));
            outputArray.push_back(float(sin((pi / 180 * k))));
    }
}
return outputArray;
```

}

**Render method:**

```
void RenderScene6(){

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    Projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    View = glm::lookAt(
    glm::vec3(5.63757, 1.7351, -2.19067), 
    glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), 
    glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)  
    );

    Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);

    MVP = Projection * View * Model; 
    glUseProgram(programID_1); 
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,                  
        3,                  
        GL_FLOAT,           
        GL_FALSE,           
        0,                  
        (void*)0            
        );

glDrawArrays(GL_QUAD_STRIP, 0, 437);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 438, 888); //THESE ARE HARDCODED ATM.
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the size you are passing to `glBufferData`: `sizeof(bufferData)` is the same as `std::vector<float>` and has nothing to do with the size of the vectors data.

What you have to do is to pass the actual size of the data stored in the vector as follows:

```
glBufferData(
    GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    bufferData.size() * sizeof(float),
    &bufferData.front(),
    GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```